# How does Django handles multiple urls per url instance in Django Rest Framework's DefaultRouter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to figure out how Django handles Django Rest Framework's DefaultRouter

Here is the use case for [DefaultRouter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/)

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from snippets import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'snippets', views.SnippetViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
# Additionally, we include the login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

The `DefaultRouter` return a list of `urls` from [router.urls](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py)

```
def get_urls(self):
    """
    Use the registered viewsets to generate a list of URL patterns.
    """
    ret = []

    for prefix, viewset, basename in self.registry:
        lookup = self.get_lookup_regex(viewset)
        routes = self.get_routes(viewset)

        for route in routes:

            # Only actions which actually exist on the viewset will be bound
            mapping = self.get_method_map(viewset, route.mapping)
            if not mapping:
                continue

            # Build the url pattern
            regex = route.url.format(
                prefix=prefix,
                lookup=lookup,
                trailing_slash=self.trailing_slash
            )
            view = viewset.as_view(mapping, **route.initkwargs)
            name = route.name.format(basename=basename)
            ret.append(url(regex, view, name=name))

    return ret
```

However it seems like the include [function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/__init__.py) don't really decompose a list of urls

Does some other code do the decomposition?

I would imagine the `include` function do something like the following

```
for url_instance in arg:
    # perform the include logic for each url_instance
```

I think I am missing some part, any hint would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The `include()` function actually includes just a _list_  of `url()` instances, no decomposing.

Comment: When I look into the `include` function it seems like it only take care of one `url` instance , can you point out the code that deals with multiple `url` instance ?